# Siddhi query with snapshots and Hazelcast Error

Tags: wso2, hazelcast, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I'm trying to create a query with snapshot output, it works fine when distributed is disabled, but fails when distributed enabled.

If i try to insert n events, it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (n)

Any idea?

```
14/03/26 18:54:05 INFO partition.PartitionService: [172.19.0.106]:5701 [CEP-Cluster] Initializing cluster partition table first arrangement...
14/03/26 18:54:05 ERROR handler.TableHandlerProcessor: 9
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.event.ListEvent.getEvent(ListEvent.java:47)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.output.ratelimit.snapshot.GroupByPerSnapshotOutputRateManager.send(GroupByPerSnapshotOutputRateManager.java:46)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.output.ratelimit.snapshot.WrappedSnapshotOutputRateManager.send(WrappedSnapshotOutputRateManager.java:88)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.QuerySelector.sendEvents(QuerySelector.java:340)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.QuerySelector.process(QuerySelector.java:301)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.processor.handler.SimpleHandlerProcessor.processHandler(SimpleHandlerProcessor.java:133)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.processor.handler.SimpleHandlerProcessor.run(SimpleHandlerProcessor.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know Siddhi still not support rate limiting in the distributed mode[1].

This may be because of that.

[1]https://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP310/Output+Rate+Limiting

Comment: Did you find this info in the official documentation? I'm trying to find an official answer to this limitation.

Comment: Edited the answer with the doc link